# How to query DynamoDB with any value in the sort key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple table with userId, pictureURL and a few other fields.
I want to return all the fields with a certain userId but when I do

```
dynamodb.get({
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: {
    'userid': '39e1f6cb-22af-4f8c-adf5-xxxxxxxxxx'
  }
}, ...
```

I get `The provided key element does not match the schema` since it seems like it requires also the sort key. When I do

```
dynamodb.get({
  TableName: tableName,
  Key: {
    'userid': '39e1f6cb-22af-4f8c-adf5-xxxxxxxxxx',
    'pictureurl': '' // Or null
  }
}, ...
```

I get an error `One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string`

So how do I query for any value in the sort key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the DynamoDB [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html):

- to query for a number of items, you use [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property)
- to get a single item, you use [get](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property)

So, use query and use the `KeyConditionExpression` parameter to provide a specific value for the partition key. The query operation will return all of the items from  the table (or index) with that partition key value.

Here's an example:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

const params = {
  TableName: tableName,
  KeyConditionExpression: '#userid = :userid',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#userid': 'userid',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':userid': '39e1f6cb-22af-4f8c-adf5-xxxxxxxxxx',
  },
};

const dc = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

dc.query(params, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  } else {
    for (const item of data.Items) {
      console.log('item:', item);
    };
  }
});
```

Comment: He might be referring to the `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` interface, which indeed exposes a `get` method.

Comment: I think it is essential to add that the `query` method only allows an equality check on the partition key, and equality, less/more, and `begins_with` queries on the sort key, and that's it.